# How can I increase max_excution time?

Tags: zend-framework, memcached

I want to generate a table containing url or links for all the data in 10 tables .

I created a table (contentUrl) then I got id and name from each table , generated the url for all data in each table and finally inserted those urls to contentUrl table.

When the code executed I found this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in path/Doctrine/Cache/Memcache.php**

How can I solve this error? Can I increase the Memory or execution time for Memcache? 
I am using Zend Framework

Comment: That error is a symptom of a problem in your code. You want to solve the problem, not hide the symptom. Narrow down the piece of code which is hitting the maximum execution time and look for problems in it.

Comment: I tested my code in limited number of rows and it worked successfully but when i removed limits error appeared

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

But I presume, you memcache server was not reachable. Check your memcache server details.